# React Multiple Condition Check(JSX)

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering

I've been trying to do some conditional rendering based on the user that is logged in. Is there a way in React JSX to check if more than one condition is true? I know this syntax is wrong but is there a way I can do this with just JSX. I basically want to check if the post array is empty and if the loading variable is false.

```
{filteredPosts.length === 0 && loading === false ? "This user has no posts" :  <Posts loading={loading} fetchData={fetchData} posts={filteredPosts}/>}
```

Comment: make the ternary wrap your whole condition

Comment: @emre-ozgun yeah I just did that and it worked. Appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
{(filteredPosts.length === 0 && loading === false) ? "This user has no posts" :  <Posts loading={loading} fetchData={fetchData} posts={filteredPosts}/>}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks man!